# Hibernate Setup on Webservice Intellij

Tags: java, hibernate, rest

I am trying to setup a REST API using Hibernate as my ORM Mapper. As IDE I am using IntelliJ. The project folder structure looks like this:
[projectstructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfLhE.jpg)

I setup the project with Glassfish like this [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service.html)

The REST-API part works fine so I won't bother pasting all of that in here. To test the Hibernate functionality I wrote this class:

```
public class ArtistRepository {



    public static void testHibernate(){
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("emf");
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();

        Artist green = new Artist();
        green.setName("TEST");

        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(green);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

The persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="emf">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>


        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoReconnect=true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="*****" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="*****" />


            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I request a REST resource using that method I get the following error:

```
<p>
            <b>exception</b>
            <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named emf</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>root cause</b>
            <pre>javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named emf</pre>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>note</b>
            <u>The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  5.0  logs.</u>
        </p>
```

So obviousley the persistence.xml is in the wrong directory, but I have no clue where to put it.

Comment: Meanwhile I tried putting the persistence.xml everywhere I could:
https://imgur.com/a/kh4f5 All of these places yield the same result

Comment: Slowly loosing my mind over this shit :^)