# Java ORM Rest API

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, orm

I have been trying to get a really simple basic REST API to work on Java using hibernate as my ORM mapper. 
I tried following this guide:
1. [IntelliJ Tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service.html)
2. [Spring MVC with Hibernate](https://www.boraji.com/spring-mvc-4-hibernate-5-restful-crud-operations-example)

The problems I ran into:
1. Setting up was easy, but as soon as I started using Hibernate which runs just fine inside a main method the whole thing crashes down and says it can not find the persistence.xml, so I literally put it in every possible combination of directories in the project but it still just does not work. The issue is can be found here: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551397/hibernate-setup-on-webservice-intellij)

2. I applied the tutorial to my needs and it builds successfull but I can not get it to work when I run "mvn tomcat7:run" but I can not test it locally in the browser, so I tried packaging a war file but that does not work because the way the project is set up it is not a webproject and therefore has no web.xml and I do not know if I can fix it that issue.

**So my question is does someone have a working tutorial of how to create a REST API with Hibernate as my ORM in IntelliJ, yielding a .war when building which I can toss at any webserver?**

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: spring boot is good for this sort of thing. You can build the app as a jar that contains a production tomcat that you deploy and run. This is a tutorial on REST+Hibernate+Spring. From the screenshot it looks like IntelliJ although any IDE is fine https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks works like a charm.